# update cart items quantities in database table php

Tags: php, mysql, input, cart, items

I have a basic shopping cart by sending values to table in database, while I generate cart id number and save it in session and cookie. then I send data to database table.

there is a remove button to every item so I can easily remove an item. But the hard thing is I have one updating link. So how can I update all items quantities by clicking on that link.

These are the cart items table

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Change character set to utf8
$conn -> set_charset("utf8");

 $sql = "
 SELECT * 
   FROM products 
   JOIN cart_items 
     ON products.product_id = cart_items.product_id 
  WHERE cart_id = '$cart_num'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  $totalSum = 0;
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                                echo'<tr>';
                                    echo'<td class="cart-pic first-row"><img src="img/cart-page/product-1.jpg" alt=""></td>';
                                    echo'<td class="cart-title first-row">';
                                        echo'<h5>'.$row['name'].'</h5>';
                                    echo'</td>';
                                    echo'<td class="p-price first-row">$'.$row['price'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td class="qua-col first-row">';
                                        echo'<div class="quantity">';
                                            echo'<div class="pro-qty">';
                                                echo'<input type="text" value="'.$row['quantity'].'">';
                                            echo'</div>';
                                        echo'</div>';
                                    echo'</td>';
                                    $one_to_price = $row['quantity'] * $row['price'];
                                    $one_formatted_price = number_format($one_to_price, 2, '.', '');
                                    echo'<td class="total-price first-row">$'.$one_formatted_price.'</td>';
                                    $totalSum += $one_to_price;
                                    echo'<td class="close-td first-row">';
                                    echo'<form action="/shopping-cart.php" method="post">';
                                    echo'<input type="hidden" name="del_id" value="'.$row['product_id'].'">';
                                    echo'<button type="submit" class="none-btn">';
                                    echo'<i class="ti-close"></i>';
                                    echo'</button>';
                                    echo'</form>';
                                    echo'</td>';
                                echo'</tr>';

  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

quantity input field in previews code

```
echo'<input type="text" value="'.$row['quantity'].'">';
```

and after the items table, The update link

```
<a href="#" class="primary-btn up-cart">Update cart</a>
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to update all products' quantities just with a single click? And do share your html code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Is there any reason you're building your own ecommerce platform instead of leveraging an existing one like [Magento](https://magento.com) or building on a platform like [Laravel](https://laravel.com)?

Comment: Pro tip: NEVER use `SELECT *`